# Why failed to register a service worker?

Tags: service-worker, progressive-web-apps

I am working on the [progressive web application sample](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/codelabs/your-first-pwapp/).
Following the instruction, I am on the step of register service worker.

This is the code for register service worker:

```
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
  navigator.serviceWorker.register('./service-worker.js').then(function () {
    console.log('Service Worker Registered');
  });
}
```

But it is always failed and get the error log as:

[image]

Could you please teach me why I cannot register the service worker?

Comment: is file 'service-worker.js'  in the root folder of your app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your service worker is not linked properly. Mentioned path is not correct and so it’s getting 404 response. Remove the “.” In the path and place service worker and the file containing this script in same place.

Comment: Thanks. but your method doesn't work. The service worker is not created in any folders... In addition, I follow the instructions from beginning, it didn't mention change path and replace the file...

Comment: I'm not talking about "my method" here. I'm pointing at the issue based on the screenshot you have attached. Post your list of files from your screenshot and URL to the site you have created(you can host free in github pages, including many others).